# Run react-native app created using react-native-cli in expo

Tags: react-native

I am a react-native beginner. 
In the earlier tutorials I did, I created apps using `react-native init AppName` but now there is a new method of using `create-react-native-app AppName`.
Apps created using the later method are run using expo.
I am wondering how I can run my old apps created using the react-native-cli in expo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exp convert` command of the `exp` command line tool to basically do this.

For more help please check here [expo commands](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/guides/exp-cli.html#commands).

If it is not work for you then please check [Converting an existing project to work with Expo](https://github.com/expo/xde#converting-an-existing-project-to-work-with-expo)

Also please check same question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833545/converting-existing-react-native-projects-to-expo).

Hope this will help you!