# Cannot run React Native project with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an old React Native project, now i want to run it with Expo. The problem is Expo software stuck at “waiting for package and tunnel to start” when i try to use Expo to open the project and start it. I am working on MacOS with watchman already installed.

Here's the structure of my project [image]

My app.json:

```
{ "name": "myapp", "displayName": "myApp", "expo": { "sdkVersion": "28.0.0" } }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.42.0",
    "react-native-calendar-strip": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-check-box": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "1.17.0-beta",
    "react-native-collapsible": "0.8.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.6",
    "react-native-image-picker": "0.26.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.9",
    "react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
    "react-native-modalbox": "1.3.9",
    "react-native-pdf": "1.2.4",
    "react-native-picker": "4.0.18",
    "react-native-signature-pad": "git+https://github.com/silverspace/react-native-signature-pad/#greg/android_blank_workaround",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "5.0.3",
    "realm": "2.11.0",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "2.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "tipsi-stripe": "3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

index.ios.js and and index.android.js have the same code: import './App';

Here's my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  AppState,
  DeviceEventEmitter
} from 'react-native';
import { BackAndroid } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './app/store'
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';
import HomeNavigation from './app/Home/screens/HomeNavigation'
import simpleStore from 'react-native-simple-store';

import { HOST } from './app/Common/constants';
const GET_USER_URL = `${HOST}/api/user`;

let codePushOptions = {
   checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME,
   installMode: codePush.InstallMode.ON_NEXT_RESUME
};

class App extends React.Component {

   //Doing something here...

    render(){
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <HomeNavigation />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default CodePushApp = codePush(codePushOptions)(App);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MypApp', () => CodePushApp);
```

I have try to install Expo on a Window PC but still have the same issues when try to run this project.

Comment: I think this could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502235/run-react-native-app-created-using-react-native-cli-in-expo

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but if you have already installed expo-cli then try changing  the scripts section of your package.json file to the following

```
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"eject": "expo eject",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"test": "jest"
```

}

This worked for me