# how to run react native app in aws workspace windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to know whether it is possible or not. 
I want to run react native app in aws workspace. Currently when i am trying to run react-native run-android in aws workspace it says it doesn't support simulators since it requires intel hardware to be enabled. And it will not be possible in aws workspace. Just want to know is there any alternative simulators that i can use in aws workspace to run react native app.

I tried using aws amplify but it is for authentication purpose but not for running a react native app in aws windows instance.

Comment: you can use expo client

Comment: i that an option ?

Comment: and if you really want to have a simulator on amazon workspace then try genny motion emulator but it will be slow without hardware accelaration

Comment: Thanks for the reply varnit. I see that genny motion emulator is just a url opens a emulator. But how do i actually integrate with react native. if i type react native run-android how to open that genny emulator

Comment: You can install expo client in genny motion to integrate it with react native

Comment: in aws machine expo is installed. So if i use genny motion then can i run the expo client in genny motion? How to integrate expo client with aws?

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode

Comment: My code is built with react native create react app. It is ejected one. Will that support ? Thanks for the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833545/converting-existing-react-native-projects-to-expo

Comment: People tried it

Comment: i have found this great reference you need to set the path of genny motion https://medium.com/@devmrin/complete-how-to-create-react-native-app-with-genymotion-android-emulator-on-windows-10-in-10-3834fd90b074

Comment: Thanks varnit i will look into the link which you shared and will update here.

Comment: @varnit i just followed this link https://medium.com/@devmrin/complete-how-to-create-react-native-app-with-genymotion-android-emulator-on-windows-10-in-10-3834fd90b074 in aws. I got the error "Genymotion requires atleast OpenGL2.0 support". Seems in aws open gl doesn't support. Any other way can you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out after a long research let me list out some options you have here to run react native app on an EC2 machine or Amazon workspace.

**AWS Device Farms**

AWS device farms in a managed service which test your apps against real devices, its the best option if budget is not a problem as AWS device farms is an expensive service (0.17$ per minute) at the time of writing.

[AWS Device Farms official page](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm)

**Genymotion Cloud**

Gennymotion cloud is a cheaper alternative to AWS device farms it deploys on amazon ec2 and available on aws marketplace as AMI.

[Gennymotion cloud AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MREUQPU/)

**Rovello Systems**

Rovello Systems is owned by Oracle and it supports nested virtualization you can signup in Ravello and then you will be able to run the android emulator in your ec2.

[Rovello Systems](https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/ravello)

**Expo Client**

Expo Client is the easiest way to test your react native app on android and ios, just install the expo client app and cli and you can test it on the real device at no cost.

[Expo client](https://expo.io/)

**Remote ADB**

Another workaround is to use remote ADB however for this you have to use a rooted android phone, roms like lineage os provide this option as an inbuilt option.

**USB Redirect**

Last and just another workaround is to redirect USB to EC2 server, many remote desktop clients support to redirect the USB to a remote computer so you can connect the Android device in your local computer and redirect it to ec2 server.

if you know any other method please mention it in comment box I'm open for discussion

Comment: i subscribed to genymotion cloud pass. I am able to launch emulator in the browser. But i am unable to run react native app in that emulator. Do you know how to configure react native android command to run in the geny motion cloud emulator.

Comment: its very easy you need to enable adb on your genny motion emulator and then connect adb through network with adb connect command then you would be able to run your react native projects on emulator for more reference you can follow the below links https://www.genymotion.com/help/cloud-paas/tutorial/enable-disable-adb/ and https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: Thanks Varnit i could able to run react native apps in genymotion.

Comment: I've been searching for this answer the whole day. Thanks!