# In React Native I need to lock orientation to portrait, but allow full screen videos to rotate

Tags: react-native, video, android-orientation

The current application uses the following directive in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    // ...
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    // ...
```

It's using the WebView component to display Youtube videos:

```
<WebView
    height={webViewRoundedHeight}
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
    useWebKit={true}
    allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
/>
```

The problem is that when the user watches a video and changes to full screen mode, the device is still locked to portrait. iOS handles this, so it's an Android only problem.

I've tried stripping back the `WebView` attributes to the minimal required to allow a video to go full screen. That had no effect on rotation.

If I remove the `ndroid:screenOrientation="portrait"` directive from the manifest, I can rotate the video but the styling across the rest of the app is broken when the user moves to landscape mode.

The app is not using `Expo` and is pre-AndroidX. This seems to have prevented me from using the `react-native-orientation` or `react-native-orientation-locker` packages, as the build fails. (I've tried following instructions for installation, but after a series of increasingly obscure error messages I'm running out of time I can spend on this feature.) It also means I don't have access to the expo screen orientation package (and adding expo to the existing app looks like it could cause more time consuming issues: [Converting Existing React Native Projects to Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833545/converting-existing-react-native-projects-to-expo) )

If I could get any of the orientation packages working I could in theory remove the portrait directive from the manifest file, lock the orientation in code (either in `App.js` or in individual screens depending on the scope of the effect), then send a message from the JS inside the web view when the user goes full screen. I could catch this in RN JS code and relax the orientation lock until the user exits full screen. However, I'm stuck trying to create a lock that I can manipulate from JS.

Alternative ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: One source I found suggested using react-native-youtube, but our lead RN developer tells me that using it will block applications from being released on the Apple store.

Comment: DId you ever find out a solution to this? Im having the same issue using our own video player.  Using a different library isn't an option for us

Comment: Sorry @Cheyne I left both the project and the company where this was necessary.